# Which one grows asymptotically faster $g(n) = 10^{79} n \log n$ or $f(n) = 3^{\log n}$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm trying to understand which of the following functions

$$g(n) = 10^{79} n \log n$$

and

$$f(n) = 3^{\log n}$$

grows asymptotically faster.

I know $f(n) = n^{\log n}$. I tried to compare the log of both functions above, that is

$$\log g(n) = \log {10^{79} n \log n} = \log {10^{79}} + \log n + \log (\log n)$$

and

$$\log f(n) = \log {3^{\log n}} = \log 3 * \log n$$

Asymptotically, $\log n$ dominates $\log (\log n)$ and $\log {10^{79}}$ becomes irrelevant. $\log 3$ is also a constant and asymptotically does not matter, but it's a multiplicative constant, so I'm tempted to say that $f$ actually grows faster asymptotically. Am I correct? If I am correct, does this hold for every base of logarithms?

Any other cleverer way to show which function grows asymptotically (i.e. as $n \to \infty$) faster?

Comment: Hint: $3^{\log n}=10^{\log n\log 3}=n^{\log 3}$ and $(\log n)^s$ is slower than $n$, for all $s>0$

Comment: Hint: $3^{log\ n} = n^{log\ 3}$

Comment: What base log are you using?

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually, I assumed (in the other comparisons) the base of the logarithms is $10$.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Oh, sorry, I actually already know that. I forgot to add it to my question. Still, I'm not sure which one grows faster.

Comment: How is $3^{\log n}$ and $n^{\log n}$ the same?

Comment: It depends on your base@nbro

Comment: @Arthur, the second term has $log\ 3$

Comment: For base 10, we have $n^{log\ 3}\lt n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base $10$ logs as specified in a comment

$3^{\log_{10} n}=3^{\log_{10}3 \cdot \log_3 n}=n^{\log_{10}3}\lt n$

Note how this would change if the base for the log were $e$ or $2$

Comment: So $g(n)$ must grow faster asymptotically than $f$, for logarithms of base $10$. If the base was $2$, then $\log_2 3 \approx 1.58$, thus $f(n) = n^{1.58} > n \sqrt n = n^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Would this grow faster asymptotically than $n \log n$? Yes, because $\sqrt n$ grows faster than $\log n$.

Comment: That is correct.  Given the $10^{79}$ factor in $g$ I would guess that the answer is supposed to be $f$ grows faster and therefore the logs have to be base $e$ or $2$.  The factor does not matter except to make $g$ huge compared to $f$ for small $n$.  I am prone to assume that the ranking will change for large $n$, but that is just experience with  problems, not mathematical truth.

Comment: In fact $n^{1+\epsilon}$ grows faster than $n \log n$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, so even base $e$ logs (or any base less than $3$) will make $f$ grow faster.

Comment: Why for any $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: One way would be to use L'hospital rule on $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\;\frac{n^\varepsilon}{log\ n}$

Comment: Because logs grow very slowly.  This is a result you should be familiar with.  As long as $k \gt 0$ (but think of it as small) $\frac d{dn} \frac {n^k}{\log n}=\frac {kn^{k-1}\log n-n^{k-1}}{\log^2 n} \gt 0$ for $\log n \gt \frac 1k$ where I used natural logs but it doesn't matter.